# How Var (variable) excecuted in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

**PROBLEM SOLVED, Thank you**

I just want to know how var (variable) in nodejs excecuted? Like this simple code, I open command promtp then

```
node
```

then

```
var test = require('./belajar.js');
```

in belajar.js only one line code

```
console.log('Hello World');
```

How come **var** getting excecuted? Who call that var? I can change var test with sjfaljflsafl and its still work.

Comment: You called it :) . You required the file and node process it. That's expected behaviour. If you don't want it to get executed immediately then you can do this `module.exports = function(){ console.log('Hello World'); }` if you try it now in command prompt it won't get executed, you would need to call test();

Comment: sorry my bad, i just test with native javascript with var = console.log(); It is run also, it means javascript will excecuted the var.

Comment: It even works without a `var`! Proof: `require('./belajar.js')`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'm understanding your question.

`var test = require('./belajar.js');`

and

`sjfaljflsafl = require('./belajar.js');`

will both work. Using `var` is better practice and the second example does not work in `strict mode`. When you use `var` the variable will be scoped to the block you are in. If you don't, it will fall back to the global scope.

`var` doesn't get "executed". `require` is executed and it's return value (which is undefined in this case) is assigned to the variable.

Comment: my point is how come var get excecuted? I test it with native javascript, var= console.log("Hello"); It is also work. What I think is var just var, untill we call it. In PHP we cannot do $var = echo "Hello". We need $var = "Hello" then echo $var;

Comment: @ucon89 but `var test = console.log("hello");` is more like `$test = print("hello");` it will get executed too

Comment: @Molda your answer make me understand. Programming language (JS, PHP, etc) still executed variable even we do not call. I thought var only executed when we call it. Thank you very much ! Problem Solved.

Answer (score 0):

When you start node from the command line as you are (without any arguments), it begins the node REPL - Read Evaluate Print Loop.  So everytime you hit enter, it will execute the code.

[NODE REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html)

It's similar to just calling the file in node:

```
node belajar.js
```